# operator how to get the correct value

Tags: python, operator-keyword

```
def start_when(iterable,p):
    s = ''
    a = ''
    x = iter(iterable)
    for x in list(iterable):
        a = a + x
    try:
        while True:
            y = next(x)
            if p(y) == True:
                s = s + a[a.index(y):]
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return s
```

The start_when generator takes an iterable and a predicate as parameters: it produces every value from the iterable, starting with the first value for which the predicate returns True
for example:

```
for i in start_when('combustible', lambda x : x >= 'q’):
    print(i,end='')
```

it prints 'ustible'

it gives me the error below:

```
    21 *Error: ''.join([str(v) for v in start_when('abcdefghijk', lambda x : x >='d')]) raised exception TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator
    22 *Error: ''.join([str(v) for v in start_when(hide('abcdefghijk'), lambda x : x >='d')]) raised exception TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator
    23 *Error: ''.join([str(v) for v in start_when(hide('abcdefghijk'), lambda x : x >'f')]) raised exception TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator
```

Can someone help me to fix it? thanks a lot

Comment: Your `else: continue` does nothing. The loop would have continued anyway.

Comment: Your `p` is a function, your `y` is an item from iterable... They will never return true on comparision and therefore your `s` will never be appended any values

Comment: You're not calling the predicate. On a side note, `d.index(y)` will produce incorrect results when your string contains duplicates

Comment: How does `s += d[d.index(y):]` work? Concatenating a string to a slice of a list would raise a `TypeError`

Comment: I am not sure what is the right way to call p...

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your code: `lambda x : x >= 'q’` should be `lambda x : x >= 'q'`

Comment: Can someone tell me the right way to call p? thank you

Comment: It's not a bout right or wrong way of calling it. It's the fact that you are not calling it at all.

Comment: I am not sure how to call, if a lambda function is the input.  is it something like p(x) ?

Comment: Yes. In your case `p(y)`. But you code is still has incorrect logic. So it won't work.

Comment: There is already a function for that : itertools.dropwhile(), if you need to use your own function you can still look at the code in the doc.

Comment: I have changed my code a little bit. now it gives me the error that 'str' object is not an iterator. I am not sure which part is wrong.

Comment: Your variable names are wrong.

Comment: which one ?????

Comment: I want to say all of them, but I would instead say the one you use for 2 very different things.